# How to place rotated labels within a GeometryReader

Tags: swiftui

I have the below, which is trying to do a bar chart with a couple of sets of labels, one set rotated. In the below, I'm using a GeometryReader to allocated half the space to the actual bars.

I then place 2 sets of labels below, the first set is fine, but the 2nd set (which is rotated) ends up on top of the first set. What's a clean way to get the 2nd set of labels to appear below the 1st set?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            let width = geometry.size.width / 3.0
            VStack {
                Text("Chart").font(.title)
                HStack(alignment: .bottom, spacing: 0.0) {
                    Rectangle().fill(.blue).frame(width: width, height: geometry.size.height/2.0)
                    Rectangle().fill(.orange).frame(width: width, height: geometry.size.height/2.0 * 0.7)
                    Rectangle().fill(.red).frame(width: width, height: geometry.size.height/2.0 * 0.88)
                }
                Divider()
                HStack {
                    Text("100%").frame(width: width)
                    Text("70%").frame(width: width)
                    Text("88%").frame(width: width)
                }
                Divider()
                HStack {
                    Text("1somelonglabel").rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 90.0))
                    Text("2somelonglabel").rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 90.0))
                    Text("3somelonglabel").rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 90.0))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Here's some updated code, with more bars. While the rotated labels are now underneath the 1st set, they are getting truncated because it seems that even after rotation the original width is taken into account. The whole point of rotation is to be able to fit the label, so not sure how to get them to occupy the available space after rotation.

```
struct Entry: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var label: String
    var value: Double
    var color: Color
    
    func labelPercentage() -> String {
        let percentage = value * 100.0
        return String(format: "%.0f", percentage) + "%"
    }
}

struct Entries {
    var entries: [Entry] = []
    
    init() {
        entries.append( Entry(id: 1, label: "short", value: 0.3, color: .blue) )
        entries.append( Entry(id: 2, label: "medium", value: 0.5, color: .orange) )
        entries.append( Entry(id: 3, label: "label2", value: 0.0, color: .gray) )
        entries.append( Entry(id: 4, label: "longerlabel12", value: 0.3, color: .black) )
        entries.append( Entry(id: 5, label: "label12", value: 0.7, color: .red) )
        entries.append( Entry(id: 6, label: "another333", value: 0.6, color: .green) )
        entries.append( Entry(id: 7, label: "another", value: 0.0, color: .purple) )
        entries.append( Entry(id: 8, label: "medium123", value: 0.1, color: .yellow) )
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    var entries: Entries
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            let width = geometry.size.width / CGFloat(entries.entries.count) - 8.0
            let height = geometry.size.height / 2.0
            let offset = width / 2.0
            VStack {
                Text("Chart").font(.title)
                HStack(alignment: .bottom, spacing: 4.0) {
                    ForEach(entries.entries) { entry in
                        Bar(color: entry.color, percentage: entry.value, width: width, height: height)
                    }
                }
                Divider()
                HStack {
                    ForEach(entries.entries) { entry in
                        Text(entry.labelPercentage()).font(.caption).frame(width: width)
                    }
                }
                Divider()
                HStack {
                    ForEach(entries.entries) { entry in
                        Text(entry.label).lineLimit(1)
                            .frame(width: width, alignment: .topLeading)
                            .offset(x: offset, y: 0)
                            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 90.0)).border(.red, width: 3)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Bar: View {
    var color: Color
    var percentage: Double
    var width: Double
    var height: Double
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            Rectangle().fill(.white).frame(width: width, height: height).opacity(0.0) // Want the full height
            Rectangle().fill(color).frame(width: width, height: height * percentage)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
       // ContentView(words: Words(numWords: 200))
        ContentView(entries: Entries())
    }
}
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: For graph with rotated labels next should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/61516570/12299030.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, based on the info in one of the comments (using an overlay on a Rectangle), I finally got what I wanted:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Entry: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var label: String
    var value: Double
    var color: Color
    
    func labelPercentage() -> String {
        let percentage = value * 100.0
        return String(format: "%.0f", percentage) + "%"
    }
}

struct Entries {
    var entries: [Entry] = []
    
    init() {
        entries.append( Entry(id: 1, label: "short", value: 0.3, color: .blue) )
        entries.append( Entry(id: 2, label: "medium", value: 0.5, color: .orange) )
        entries.append( Entry(id: 3, label: "label2", value: 0.0, color: .gray) )
        entries.append( Entry(id: 4, label: "longerlabel12", value: 0.3, color: .black) )
        entries.append( Entry(id: 5, label: "label12", value: 0.7, color: .red) )
        entries.append( Entry(id: 6, label: "another333", value: 0.6, color: .green) )
        entries.append( Entry(id: 7, label: "another", value: 0.0, color: .purple) )
        entries.append( Entry(id: 8, label: "medium123", value: 0.1, color: .yellow) )
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    var entries: Entries
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            let width = geometry.size.width / CGFloat(entries.entries.count) - 8.0
            let height = geometry.size.height / 2.0

            VStack {
                Text("Chart").font(.title)
                HStack(alignment: .bottom, spacing: 4.0) {
                    ForEach(entries.entries) { entry in
                        Bar(color: entry.color, percentage: entry.value, width: width, height: height)
                    }
                }
                Divider()
                HStack(spacing: 4) {
                    ForEach(entries.entries) { entry in
                        Text(entry.labelPercentage()).font(.caption).frame(width: width)
                    }
                }
                Divider()
                HStack(spacing: 4) {
                    ForEach(entries.entries) { entry in
                        Rectangle().foregroundColor(.white)
                            .frame(width: width, height: height/2.0)
                            .overlay(
                                Text(entry.label)
                                    .font(.caption)
                                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                                    .fixedSize()
                                    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 90), anchor: .leading)
                                    .offset(x: width / 2.0, y: 0)
                                , alignment: .topLeading)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Bar: View {
    var color: Color
    var percentage: Double
    var width: Double
    var height: Double
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            Rectangle().fill(.white).frame(width: width, height: height).opacity(0.0) // Want the full height
            Rectangle().fill(color).frame(width: width, height: height * percentage)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(entries: Entries())
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is that `.rotationEffect()` is rotating the `Text()` around its center. Since the `Text()` is right below the `Divider()` when it spins, half of it obscures the views above. So, you simply need to move the label to the right which, when rotating clockwise, moves it down. I simply used half of your width, which is enough for this example. I also put it in a frame to prevent the label from getting too long.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            let width = geometry.size.width / 3.0
            let offset = width / 2.0
            VStack {
                Text("Chart").font(.title)
                HStack(alignment: .bottom, spacing: 0.0) {
                    Rectangle().fill(.blue).frame(width: width, height: geometry.size.height/2.0)
                    Rectangle().fill(.orange).frame(width: width, height: geometry.size.height/2.0 * 0.7)
                    Rectangle().fill(.red).frame(width: width, height: geometry.size.height/2.0 * 0.88)
                }
                Divider()
                HStack {
                    Text("100%").frame(width: width)
                    Text("70%").frame(width: width)
                    Text("88%").frame(width: width)
                }
                Divider()
                HStack {
                    Text("1somelonglabel").frame(width: width).offset(x: offset, y: 0).rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 90.0))
                    Text("2somelonglabel").frame(width: width).offset(x: offset, y: 0).rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 90.0))
                    Text("3somelonglabel").frame(width: width).offset(x: offset, y: 0).rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 90.0))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that looks right, except that in my real case, I have something like 8 bars. And the whole point of rotating the labels is because they don't fit underneath each bar. The problem is that the label text is truncated because the "width" is the width of each column, and this width seems to carry over to the Text field *after* rotation. Even if I specify a height, it ignores it and uses the original width as the "height" for the rotated text.